# Error de certificado de seguridad

Tags: java

estoy intentando conectarme a un servidor ISAM usando este simple código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class PruebaConexionISAM {
    
    private static final String endpoint = "https://xxxxx/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token";
    public static String respuestaJson;     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL obj;
        Object objRespuesta = null; 

        try {
            System.out.println(endpoint);
            String urlParameters  = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=openid&client_id=sid&client_secret=yyyyyyyyyy";
            byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
            int    postDataLength = postData.length;            
            obj = new URL(endpoint);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);

            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            con.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");        
            
            con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
            con.setUseCaches( false );
            try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream())) {
               wr.write( postData );
            }           
                        
            
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("IOException");
            System.err.println(e);
        }               

    }

}
```

sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error:

IOException
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Alguien podría ayudarme en corregir el error

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Segun indica el error :

```
OException javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

y como se ve en tu variable de endPoint  :

```
private static final String endpoint="https://xxxxx/mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token";
```

para poder realizar una request a un servicio por https necesitas un certificado

en este enlace en stackOverflow Ingles tienes un problema similar con sus posibles soluciones : [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore?rq=1)